# How to convert webp to gif?

Tags: java, android, gif, webp

How do I convert animated webp to gif in android?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `libwebp` Java bindings in your Android [project](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#how_do_i_use_the_libwebp_java_bindings_in_my_android_project).

Once you decode your source webp images you'd need to use a java library that supports animated gifs.

Comment: sample code please